# Set theory in practice - indexed sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[image]

Hi, I have a problem as above. And below is my first few attempts to solve a, and b.

a) $B_1 \cap \bigcup C_k = \{1, 2, 3\}$. My understanding is that the $\bigcup C_k$ in a is the set of elements that belong to at least one $C_k$ so as k is in $[1,3]$, my answer was that.

b) = $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15\}$

I have to admit that the above is all my guesses. Can someone explain the indexed sets to me in a simpler and easy-to-apply way? All theoretical definitions make me confused. It would be best if you take one problem as an example. I would really appreciate any help for this advanced course. I have to explain my steps so if you can give me answers to check, that would be great, too.

Comment: Yes, $\bigcup_k C_k = C_1 \cup C_2 \cup C_3$

Comment: According to the def, $C_1 = \{ x \text { born on Sunday } \}$ and so on and $B_1 = \{ x \text { born in January } \}$

Comment: Thus a) is "born either on Sunday or Monday or Tuesday of January"

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you, Mauro. Your explanation is awesome too. Could you please check my work for b - e under the comment section below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate $\cup$ to "or" and $\cap$ to "and" when it comes the the conditions defining the sets. So a) is for example "the people that are both (born in January) and (born Sunday, Monday or Tuesday)". Or in natural words, "the people born in Januray on a Sunday, Monday or Tuesday".

See if you can do the others now.

Your guesses right now ($\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4,5,12,13,14,15\}$) are wrong. In fact they're nonsensical because the sets contain people, not numbers. What's true is e.g.
$$
B_1\cap\left(\bigcup_{1\le k \le 3}C_k\right)
= B_1\cap\left(C_1\cup C_2\cup C_3\right)
$$
So $x\in B_1\cap\left(\bigcup_{1\le k \le 3}C_k\right)$ iff $x$ is in $B_1$ and $x$ in (at least) one of $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$. This translates to what I wrote above.

Edit:

In (d), (e), (f), we also have the $'$ meaning complement, which translates to "not". So (d) is "the people that are not (born on Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, or Thu)" = "the people that are born Fri or Sat".

There are also the general rules $\left(\bigcup_i A_i\right)' = \left(\bigcap_i A_i'\right)$ and $\left(\bigcap_i A_i\right)' = \left(\bigcup_i A_i'\right)$, which might be nice to know, but not necessary for the problem.

Help for b and e:

As I hinted in the comments (your first b was correct), b turns out to be "(something impossible) or (birthday 12th-15th)". If something's impossible it's the empty set, and in gereral $\emptyset\cap A=\emptyset$ and $\emptyset\cup A=A$. Use that.

Your e is wrong. The literal translation would be "(not born in Jan) or (not born in Feb) or ... or (not born in May)". Or equivalently with my rule above: "not (born in Jan and Feb and ... and May)". Can you figure it out from there?

Comment: awesome, your explanation is super clear for a). But I get into trouble when it comes to combining the $\bigcup$, $\bigcap$ with $\cap$ and $\cup$ later in the exercises.

Comment: These are my work:
b) the people that are either (born during Jan, Feb, Mar, April, and May) or (born on the 12th, 13th, 14th, or 15th of his/her birthday) 
c) the people that are both (born on Friday) and (born during the Jan, Feb, Mar, or Apr of the year).
d) the people that are born on everyday except Friday, and Saturday.

Comment: I'm stuck at e and f. :(

Comment: (also in (c) $C_6$ is Sat, not Fri)

Comment: So for b, I would say "the people that are either (born during either Jan, Feb, Mar, April, or May) or (born on the 12th, 13th, 14th, or 15th of his/her birthday)"?

Comment: And for e: the people that are born on Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, and Thursday

Comment: and for f: the people that are not (born during Jan, Feb, Mar, or Apr) = the people that are born during May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, or Dec.

Comment: Hi @Milten, would you mind checking if my answer to the followings are correct? The first is $x\in B_1\cap\left(\bigcap_{1\le k \le 3}C_k\right)$ $\sim$ people born in January on a Sunday, Monday, and Tuesday.

Comment: The second is $\bigcap_{1\le k \le 7}C'_k$ $\sim$ no one.

Comment: The last is $\bigcup_{1\le j \le 3}B'_j \sim$ people not born in January, February and March.